# Laravel send data such as 1-2-3 by ajax and get Missing argument error

Tags: php, laravel

i try to use below ajax to send data such as `1-2-3-4-5` to controller action but i get error:

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: " {{ url('changeMenuItemOrders') }}",
    data: {orders: "1-2-3"},
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('changeMenuItemOrders','SystemController@changeMenuItemOrders');
```

`changeMenuItemOrders` action:

```
public function changeMenuItemOrders($orders)
{
    dd($orders);
}
```

**Firebug:**

```
http://localhost/sample/public/changeMenuItemOrders?orders=1-2-3 500 Internal Server Error
```

**Laravel error:**

```
ErrorException in SystemController.php line 114: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\SystemController::changeMenuItemOrders()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is query string parameters vs routing parameters. Right now, you have:

```
public function changeMenuItemOrders($orders)
```

looking for the route parameter `$orders`. In order to make this work, you would require the route:

```
Route::get('changeMenuItemOrders/{orders}','SystemController@changeMenuItemOrders');
```

and you would access this function by navigating to (`GET`):

```
http://localhost/sample/public/changeMenuItemOrders/1-2-3
```

Since you are creating a query string via your ajax request, you shouldn't have `$orders` in your function, but you should instead be accessing the orders via the `GET` array, using

```
$orders = Input::get('orders');
```

Hope that helps clear things up. Also, as a side note, if you're passing multiple orders (ie 1, 2 and 3), consider posting an `orders[]` (`orders[0] 1, orders[1] 2, orders[2] 3`) instead of a string (`"1-2-3"`) that you would have to split on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public function changeMenuItemOrders()
{
    $orders= Input::get('orders');
    dd($orders);
}
```

in `changeMenuItemOrders action:`